# Convert HTML with scripts to RTF

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, rtf

I want to convert HTML file to RTF File. It seems easy while working with simple HTML file. But my file contains some scripts which run at page load. Hence, not able to get proper HTML.

I checked with plenty of online tool & converters but none of them support scripting.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: If the script that needs to run is actually producing parts of the output, why not 'host it in a website' and read the result 'as a browser would' (page spider for instance).

Answer (score 0):

**Run the website** - then take the output which *is* HTML (using I.E. its View -> Source)